# Convert CoseSign1 to JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptocurrency, cardano

I am trying to convert CoseSign1 to Json or something similar.

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am using Nami Wallet, and I am trying to turn the returned data from signData() to something readable (Json, or something similar).

Currently all it returns is

> 845869a301270458206ac6ea9d3fda361869f40e202d39d3533014409139d382fdac02878047c9aefb67616464726573735839012988392f2533fa3feaa52ed949b45db47ab747a1d81f1571d80966a4280075c8c2c22341e1b24b55eb9aa3a193a7a40a663e72cbfffcdd65a166686173686564f4581a436f6e6e65637420746f204e4654204d61726b6574706c616365584080e294727384373e5f93870f60a10a5915b961cecb24fa7e4d19120a8cce8a3b1c5be15285b00558eaabb11364b077b5f563405db39c121087c9701855f5500d

I am trying to do this with React / NodeJS.

Nami Wallet: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet